# How to generate an Rx-ified proxy for a Vert.x service containing a reactive PostgreSQL client?

Tags: postgresql, vert.x, reactive

I am learning Vert.x with the "Vert.x in Action" book. Following this example here:

https://github.com/jponge/vertx-in-action/tree/master/chapter6

I would like to extend the service in order to use a PostgreSQL DB. When I only change the constructor of [SensorDataServiceImpl](https://github.com/jponge/vertx-in-action/blob/master/chapter6/src/main/java/chapter6/SensorDataServiceImpl.java) from:

```
SensorDataServiceImpl(Vertx vertx) {
    vertx.eventBus().<JsonObject>consumer("sensor.updates", message -> {
      JsonObject json = message.body();
      lastValues.put(json.getString("id"), json.getDouble("temp"));
    });
}
```

to

```
SensorDataServiceImpl(Vertx vertx) {
    PgConnectOptions connectOptions = new PgConnectOptions()
            .setPort(5432)
            .setHost("host")
            .setDatabase("db")
            .setUser("user")
            .setPassword("pass")
            .setSslMode(SslMode.VERIFY_CA)
            .setPemTrustOptions(new PemTrustOptions().addCertPath("root.crt"));

    PoolOptions poolOptions = new PoolOptions().setMaxSize(5);

    io.vertx.reactivex.pgclient.PgPool dbPool = PgPool.pool(vertx, connectOptions, poolOptions);

    Single<RowSet<Row>> single = dbPool.rxQuery(sqlQueries.get(SqlQuery.CREATE_PAGES_TABLE));

    single.subscribe(result -> {
        System.out.println("Got " + result.size() + " rows ");
    }, err -> {
        System.out.println("Failure: " + err.getMessage());
    });

    vertx.eventBus().<JsonObject>consumer("sensor.updates", message -> {
        JsonObject json = message.body();
        lastValues.put(json.getString("id"), json.getDouble("temp"));
    });
}
```

I get the following problems:

1. `PgPool.pool(vertx, connectOptions, poolOptions)` expects a `io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx` object, so I change the import to that.
2. But then the `new SensorDataServiceVertxEBProxy(vertx, address)` call in the [SensorDataService](https://github.com/jponge/vertx-in-action/blob/master/chapter6/src/main/java/chapter6/SensorDataService.java) interface expects a normal `io.vertx.core.Vertx` as parameter.

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unwrap the underlying `io.vertx.core.Vertx` instance by calling [getDelegate](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/reactivex/core/Vertx.html#getDelegate--):

```
io.vertx.core.Vertx delegate = reactiveVertx.getDelegate();
```